# Why is my for loop stopping after only 9 iterations?

Tags: python, for-loop, txt

```
import pygame
import csv
import time 
from datetime import datetime

# Initialize pygame starts 
pygame.init()

# Set the dimensions of the screen
screen_width = 1275
screen_height = 750


# Set the colors
white = (255, 255, 255)
black = (0, 0, 0)

# Set the font
font = pygame.font.SysFont('Arial', 20)

# Set the button properties
button_radius = 70
button_x_spacing = 400
button_y_spacing = 200

# Set the button positions
button_positions = [
    (button_x_spacing, button_y_spacing),
    (button_x_spacing, button_y_spacing + 200),
    (button_x_spacing, button_y_spacing + 400)
]

# Initialize the screen
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((screen_width, screen_height))

# Set the caption
pygame.display.set_caption("Marmoset Buttons")

# Set the clock
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

# Set the counters
correctleft = 0
correctmiddle = 0
correctright = 0
incorrectleft = 0
incorrectmiddle = 0
incorrectright = 0
trialnum = 0
timelistleft = []
timelistmiddle = []
timelistright = []

# Psuedorandom sequence of numbers
sequence = [1,1,2,2,1,2,1,0,1,1, 1,2,1,0,1,0,1,2,1,1, 2,1,0,1,2,1,1,0,1,2, 2,1,0,2,1,1,1,0,1,1,
           1,1,0,1,1,1,2,0,2,1, 2,1,0,1,0,1,1,2,2,1, 1,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,2,2, 1,1,2,1,1,2,1,0,1,1,
           1,1,1,0,1,1,2,0,2,1, 0,1,1,2,1,0,1,2,1,0, 1,1,0,1,1,2,1,2,1,0, 2,1,2,1,1,2,1,1,0,1,
           1,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1, 1,1,2,1,1,1,0,1,1,2, 1,2,1,0,1,2,2,2,1,0, 1,2,1,0,0,1,2,1,2,0,
           1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,2,1, 0,1,2,2,1,1,1,0,1,1, 1,0,1,2,0,1,0,1,1,2, 0,1,2,1,2,1,2,2,1,0,
           1,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0, 1,2,2,1,0,1,1,2,0,1, 1,0,1,2,1,0,1,2,1,0, 1,0,1,1,2,2,1,1,0,0,
           1,2,1,2,1,1,1,0,1,0, 1,1,0,1,2,1,1,2,1,0, 1,2,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,0, 1,2,0,2,1,2,1,0,0,1,
           1,1,1,1,0,0,1,2,0,1, 0,1,2,0,1,2,1,2,1,0, 1,0,1,2,1,1,2,0,1,2, 0,0,1,0,2,1,2,1,2,1,
           1,2,2,2,1,1,2,1,1,0, 1,2,1,1,0,2,1,2,1,1, 1,2,2,1,1,2,1,0,0,1, 2,1,2,1,0,2,1,2,0,0,
           1,0,1,1,2,2,1,0,1,0, 0,1,2,1,1,0,1,2,0,1, 1,0,0,1,2,1,2,1,0,0, 1,2,0,0,2,1,0,2,1,1,
           1,1,1,1,2,1,1,0,1,1, 2,1,0,1,1,0,1,2,1,0, 0,1,2,1,2,1,0,1,2,1, 2,1,0,2,1,2,1,1,2,1,
           1,1,0,1,1,1,2,1,1,1, 2,1,2,1,0,0,1,2,1,2, 1,0,1,2,1,2,0,1,2,2, 2,0,1,2,1,2,1,0,1,1,
           1,2,1,0,1,2,0,2,2,2, 1,2,2,1,1,0,1,1,0,0, 1,1,0,1,0,0,1,2,1,2, 1,0,2,1,2,1,2,1,0,1,
           1,2,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,1, 1,1,1,2,1,1,0,1,1,1, 1,2,1,0,2,2,1,2,0,1, 1,1,2,2,1,0,1,2,1,0,
           1,2,0,1,1,0,1,1,2,1, 1,2,2,2,1,1,1,0,1,0, 1,2,0,0,0,1,2,2,0,1, 0,2,1,0,0,1,2,2,2,1,
           1,1,2,1,0,1,0,1,2,1, 1,2,1,0,1,1,2,1,0,2, 1,0,2,2,1,0,1,0,2,1, 1,0,2,1,2,1,1,0,0,1,
           1,2,1,2,1,1,1,0,1,1, 1,1,0,0,1,2,1,2,1,0, 1,2,1,2,2,1,0,1,0,0, 2,1,0,2,0,1,0,1,2,1,
           1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1, 1,2,1,0,1,0,1,2,1,0, 2,1,2,2,1,0,1,0,1,1, 2,1,2,0,1,2,1,2,0,0,
           1,1,2,0,2,1,2,1,1,0, 1,2,1,0,0,1,1,2,1,2, 1,2,2,1,1,1,1,2,0,0, 1,2,1,0,0,2,1,0,2,1,
           1,0,1,1,2,1,2,0,1,2, 2,1,0,1,1,0,1,2,1,0, 0,1,0,1,2,1,1,2,1,0, 2,2,1,0,0,1,2,1,2,1]

# Truncating list 
trials = int(input("Number of trials: "))
n = len(sequence)
for i in range(0, n - trials):
    sequence.pop()

# Settin up CSV title
AnimalName = input("Animal Name: ")
StepName = input("Step: ")
thedatetime = datetime.now()
date = thedatetime.date()
thetime = thedatetime.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
title = f"{AnimalName}_WCST_S{StepName}_{datetime.now().strftime('%Y%m%d_%H%M%S')}.csv"

# Write headers to csv file
data = open(title, 'w')
writer = csv.writer(data)
writer.writerow(["Trial#", "Event Code", "Time"])

# For loop parsing through sequence 
for i in sequence:

    trialnum += 1

    # Writing summary csv 
    if trialnum%10 == 0:
        if trialnum == 10:
            title2 = f"{AnimalName}_WCST_S{StepName}_{datetime.now().strftime('%Y%m%d_%H%M%S')}_Summary.txt"
            meanleft = sum(timelistleft) / len(timelistleft)
            meanmiddle = sum(timelistmiddle) / len(timelistmiddle)
            meanright = sum(timelistright) / len(timelistright)
            summary = open(title2, "w")
            summary.writelines("Total Trial: 10", 
            ','.join(sequence), 
            f"Correct: {correctleft},{correctmiddle},{correctright}", 
            f"Correct: {incorrectleft},{incorrectmiddle},{incorrectright}", 
            f"Total Reward: {correctleft+correctmiddle+correctright}", 
            f"Mean Reaction Times: {meanleft}, {meanmiddle}, {meanright}", 
            "------------------------------------------------------------")
            #summary.write(','.join(sequence))
            #summary.write(f"Correct: {correctleft},{correctmiddle},{correctright}")
            #summary.write(f"Correct: {incorrectleft},{incorrectmiddle},{incorrectright}")
            #summary.write(f"Total Reward: {correctleft+correctmiddle+correctright}")
            #summary.write(f"Mean Reaction Times: {meanleft}, {meanmiddle}, {meanright}")
            #summary.write("------------------------------------------------------------")
        else:
            summary.write(f"Total Trial: {trialnum}")
            summary.write(','.join(sequence))
            summary.write(f"Correct: {correctleft},{correctmiddle},{correctright}")
            summary.write(f"Correct: {incorrectleft},{incorrectmiddle},{incorrectright}")
            summary.write(f"Total Reward: {correctleft+correctmiddle+correctright}")
            summary.write(f"Mean Reaction Times: {meanleft}, {meanmiddle}, {meanright}")

    # Delay between buttons 
    screen.fill(black)
    pygame.display.update()
    pygame.time.delay(500)

    # While loop variable 
    correct = False

    # Starts Timer 
    start_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()

    # Writing the button in csv file
    timedisplay = time.time()
    writer.writerow([trialnum, i, time.asctime(time.localtime(time.time()))])

    # Loops while button isn't correct 
    while correct == False:

        # Time out for 15 seconds 
        seconds = (pygame.time.get_ticks() - start_time)/1000
        if seconds == 15:
            break

        # Checks when screen is touched 
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:

                # Distance between point touched and button 
                distance_button = pygame.math.Vector2(button_positions[i]) - pygame.math.Vector2(pygame.mouse.get_pos())

                # Checks if distance is within button 
                if distance_button.length() < button_radius:

                    correct = True
                    writer.writerow([trialnum, 150, time.asctime(time.localtime(time.time()))])

                    # Counts which buttons were pressed 
                    if i == 0:
                        timecorrect = time.time()
                        timedifference = timedisplay - timecorrect
                        timelistleft.append(timedifference)
                        correctleft += 1
                    elif i == 1:
                        timecorrect = time.time()
                        timedifference = timedisplay - timecorrect
                        timelistmiddle.append(timedifference)
                        correctmiddle += 1
                    elif i == 2:
                        timecorrect = time.time()
                        timedifference = timedisplay - timecorrect
                        timelistright.append(timedifference)
                        correctright += 1

                # Counts when touch was outside of button 
                elif distance_button.length() > button_radius:
                    x = pygame.mouse.get_pos()[0]
                    if x <= 425:
                        incorrectleft += 1
                        timenow = time.time()
                        writer.writerow([trialnum, 201, time.asctime(time.localtime(time.time()))])
                    elif x <= 850:
                        incorrectmiddle += 1
                        timenow = time.time()
                        writer.writerow([trialnum, 200, time.asctime(time.localtime(time.time()))])
                    elif x > 850:
                        incorrectright += 1
                        timenow = time.time()
                        writer.writerow([trialnum, 202, time.asctime(time.localtime(time.time()))])   

        # Draws the button 
        pygame.draw.circle(screen, white, button_positions[i], button_radius)
        text_surface = font.render(f"Button {i}", True, black)
        text_rect = text_surface.get_rect(center=button_positions[i])
        screen.blit(text_surface, text_rect)
        pygame.display.update()

# Printing results 
data.close()
summary.close()
```

I am trying to have this for loop run through the sequence for a specified number of times in the input. It was working fine until I added the summary file lines. I'm trying to create a summary txt file with some data every 10 trials. It is going through 9 times and then creating a file that is empty and exiting the code. I want it to continue going until the sequence ends.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "stopping"? Does the program exit normally, throw an exception, or stall?

Comment: Please include what the actual results and the expected results as well as the sample input.

Comment: @gmdev The program exists after 9 iterations and generates a blank txt file

Comment: @ewokx there are no results it just outputs a blank txt file. The inputs should be self explanatory. I don't think the inputs have much to do with what is going on anyways. They worked fine before I added the txt file lines.